# C / Objective-C printf and NSLog (pointer to char array)

Tags: objective-c, c, printf, nslog

Quick question on `NSLog` and `printf`:

I am running the following in Xcode:

```
char array[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
char *arrayPtr = array;

NSLog(@"TEST:  %c", *(arrayPtr+9));

printf(@"TEST:  %c", *(arrayPtr+9));
```

Every line works fine except this:

```
printf(@"TEST:  %c", *(arrayPtr+9));
```

Error:

> Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is
>   disallowed with ARC.

Could you explain to me what happens here and if a simple cast here would make it work?

`NSLog` works ok, no error whatsoever. But `printf` does. I have tried using `__bridge` cast, but it doesn't seem to satisfy it.

Is there a way to make this work without needing to turn off ARC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the `char` array or arithmetic. It's telling you that you're passing an `NSString` to `printf()` as the format string, when you need to pass a regular C string:

```
printf("TEST:  %c", *(arrayPtr+9));
//     ^ No @
```